# Changing font size in j2me

Tags: java-me, mobile

Can we change the siz,style,etc of the font (javax.microedition.lcdui.Font) in j2me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@org.life.java 
That be true that there isn't a set size method..... that being said there isn't a "setSubstring" method either.

Strings as with fonts in J2me are immutable http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object so simply create a new font with the desired properties....

http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/index.html

So instead of

```
 myfon.setSize(Font.SIZE_SMALL)
```

Do

```
myFont = Font.getFont(myFont.getFontFace(), myFont.getFontStyle(), Font.SIZE_MEDIUM)
```

That would work.

Comment: yeah but where do you set this font ?

Comment: org.life.java the above answer is not correct.In "myFont = Font.getFont(myFont.getFontFace(), myFont.getFontStyle(), 12)" , we cannot able to give the random number as font size bcause sometime it throws an exception "UnSupported size".

Comment: @org.life.java you would do something like graphics.setFont either way the original question asked how you change a Font which is immutable.

Comment: @sivakumar if you don't accept peoples answers no one will want to help you any more.  Secondly did you even bother reading the javadocs? http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/index.html I made a slight mistake example is updated